# ffmpeg errors while opening encoder … and says that there are *maybe* incorrect parameters?

Tags: ffmpeg

Just yesterday my app threw a weird ffmpeg error I cannot figure out:

*ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height*

The ffmpeg command itself was:

`ffmpeg -f image2 -thread_queue_size 2048 -framerate 15.0 -i /var/www/blahblah/frames/%d.jpg -y -an -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -loglevel info /var/www/blahblah/preview.mp4`

Basically I am just generating a MP4 based on image frames here without sound. Using ffmpeg version 3.05 here:

`ffmpeg version 3.0.5-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.2.0 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 20161005
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.10.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libx264
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...`

Can you spot anything wrong with the above command that could cause this error? And why does ffmpeg say *maybe*? Shouldn't ffmpeg be able to say exactly what caused the problem?

Also don't have the rest of the ffmpeg output unfortunately. Because the stderr event only seems to print the error message.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from the command.

Comment: I am afraid, I dont have it anymore (it was a temporary file). Really would like to know what it could be. Can't you at least say what you suspect when looking at the command?

Comment: Most commonly, that error comes up when either the width or height is not an even number.

Comment: yep, i just checked that, it's this error "height not divisible by 2 (400x225) Error while opening encoder for output"

Comment: what can i do? possible to tell ffmpeg to round it up to the second even number itself?